# strange "padding" effect at the bottom of an iframe in a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

With the code below, I'm trying to reach the following design:
1. Table width/height must be 80%/70% of a browser window. Its left cell must be 40%-wide.
2. Iframe in a right cell must fill all available space and never go beyond a cell's inner border.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title></title>
<style>
    body {width:100%}
    iframe {width:100%; overflow:auto; margin:0px; border:solid 2px red; background-color:white; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box}
    table {width:80%}
    table, td {margin:0px; padding:0px; border:solid 1px black}
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:40%">Cell 1</td>
                <td style="background-color:blue">
                    <iframe src='iframe.htm'></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('iframe').height($(window).height()*0.7);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Questions:
1. Where that thin blue "padding" space at the bottom of an iframe comes from? How to force it to never appear?
2. Is it possible to reach this design without: a) using javascript; b) using CSS `box-sizing` property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`iframe` is short for "inline frame", inline elements sit on the baseline of the surrounding text. The baseline allows for descenders (the tail of the 'g' etc.) and the white space is the space taken up by the descenders (even if there are none).

Setting `display: block;` on the `iframe` should fix the padding.

**Edit:** here's <kbd>[**an updated version of @syedmohsin's jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/spmwc/9/)</kbd>, it gets rid of `box-sizing` and it fixes your `80% width/70% height`issue for you.

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
iframe {
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    border:solid 2px red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
table {
    width:80%;
    height: 70%;
}
table, td {
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
td {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 3px 2px 0;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    td {
        padding: 0 3px 0px 0;
    }
}
@media screen\0 {
    td {
        padding: 0 3px 0px 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, that was my haste, I forgot about line-height and inline element interaction... And now I wonder how to get rid of `box-sizing:border-box`... What are the caveats if I use this property with this design?

Comment: I think you should be fine using `box-sizing`, I believe all browsers support the bit that you need to work (moving the borders to the inside of the `iframe`'s box). If you really don't want to use it, here's a [fixed up version of @syedmohsin's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spmwc/9/), which uses some browser specific hacks to add extra padding to accommodate the border.

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` is being treated as an inline element, so the table-cell aligns it to the baseline (and leaves a bit of space for descenders). You can see a similar effect with inline images.

Set `display: block` on the `iframe` ... or `line-height: 0` on the `td`